# How to fetch the data with specific id in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

How to fetch the data with specific id in spring

I am getting an error while query the data based on the id.

Here is the values in my data base.

---

### id | maxval | first_name | minval | lastname | user_id

### 1  | 12     | Ole        | 3      | Gunner   | 10

My repository code

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {
    
    @Query(value = "select * from users where user_id = :value",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Users> getUserDetails(int value);
}
```

my controller code

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")

public class UsersController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userlist;
    
    
    @GetMapping ("/userlist") 
    public List<Users> getAllUsers(){ 
      return  userlist.findAll(); 
    }
     
    @GetMapping("/userlist/{value}")
    public List<Users> getAllUsers(@PathVariable int value){
        return userlist.getUserDetails(value);
    }
    
}
```

Now here my first call is giving me response properly (/userlist) but in second call when i am trying to fetch the data i am getting 404. Can anyone explaine me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: why not use `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository::findById`?

Comment: The 404 could indicate that the page or the item was not found, are you sure you are using an existing id?

Comment: @josejuan where do i need to change that, In my repository

Comment: You can use findAllById(). It is a method that all JpaRepositories have, because it is defined in JpaRepository itself.

Comment: Your code itself should work properly in case you pass an existing user id via the `@PathVariable`. Have a look on an actual request and check whether there are any typo mistakes